# Remove Padding or Margin from Drawer Header in Flutter App

Tags: navigation-drawer, margin, padding, flutter-layout

How do I remove the padding or margin from my Drawer Header in this example below.

I've set margin and padding to EdgeInsets.zero for both but this is not doing the job.

[Menu Screen Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToP8r.png)

Here is the code that produced this menu. Everything works. I simply can't remove the padding from the header specifically. The blue field should reach all the way to the edges on the top and sides.

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Menu App',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: AppDrawer(mainMenu),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("My Menu App"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AppDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  List menuChoices;

  AppDrawer(this.menuChoices);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Drawer(
      child: ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        itemCount: menuChoices.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext cntxt, int index) {
          return _constructItem(menuChoices[index]);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _constructHeader(Choices choice) {
    return DrawerHeader(
      margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      child: Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              bottom: 12.0,
              left: 16.0,
              child: Text(
                choice.title,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _constructItem(Choices choice) {
    switch (choice.itemType) {
      case "Header":
        return DrawerHeader(child: _constructHeader(choice));
        break;

      case "Item":
        return ListTile(
            leading: Icon(choice.icon),
            title: Opacity(
              opacity: choice.enabled ? 1 : 0.5,
              child: Text(choice.title),
            ),
            onTap: choice.action,
            enabled: choice.enabled);
        break;

      case "Divider":
        return Divider(
          thickness: 2.0,
        );
        break;
    }
  }
}

class Choices {
  const Choices(
      {@required this.title,
      @required this.itemType,
      this.icon,
      this.enabled = true,
      this.action});

  final String itemType;
  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
  final bool enabled;
  final Function action;
}

// These are the menu choices
const List<Choices> mainMenu = const <Choices>[
  const Choices(
    itemType: "Header",
    title: "My Header Text",
    icon: Icons.face,
  ),
  const Choices(
    itemType: "Item",
    title: 'My Profile',
    icon: Icons.person,
    enabled: true,
    action: null,
  ),
  const Choices(
    itemType: "Divider",
  ),
  const Choices(
    itemType: "Item",
    title: 'About',
    icon: Icons.info,
    enabled: true,
    action: null,
  ),
  const Choices(
    itemType: "Divider",
  ),
  const Choices(
    itemType: "Item",
    title: 'Help',
    icon: Icons.help_outline,
    enabled: true,
    action: null,
  ),
];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Widget _constructItem(Choices choice) {
switch (choice.itemType) {
  case "Header":
    return DrawerHeader(padding: EdgeInsets.zero ,child: _constructHeader(choice));
    break;

  case "Item":
    return ListTile(
        leading: Icon(choice.icon),
        title: Opacity(
          opacity: choice.enabled ? 1 : 0.5,
          child: Text(choice.title),
        ),
        onTap: choice.action,
        enabled: choice.enabled);
    break;

  case "Divider":
    return Divider(
      thickness: 2.0,
    );
    break;
}
}
```

[image: Click here to see the result image]

Comment: Thanks very much. Your solution worked but ultimately pointed me to my error which was that I called DrawerHeader twice.

Answer (score 1):

DrawerHeader has been called both in the switch statement and in the _constructHeaderMethod. Simply calling the _constructHeaderMethod is all that is needed. Essentially I had a DrawerHeader as a child of a DrawerHeader which was unnecessary.

Changing the _constructItem method as below solves the problem.

```
Widget _constructItem(Choices choice) {
    switch (choice.itemType) {
      case "Header":
        return _constructHeader(choice);
        break;

      case "Item":
        return ListTile(
            leading: Icon(choice.icon),
            title: Opacity(
              opacity: choice.enabled ? 1 : 0.5,
              child: Text(choice.title),
            ),
            onTap: choice.action,
            enabled: choice.enabled);
        break;

      case "Divider":
        return Divider(
          thickness: 2.0,
        );
        break;
    }
  }
}
```